# Hibernate save new if dirty

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way to force hibernate to save a new instance of an object (new identifier) on saveOrUpdate when an object is dirty (been modified)?  Is this possible via configuration or Interceptor? I have three entities:

```
Entity A (has B)
Entity B
Entity C (has B)
Entity B can only be updated through A
```

Basically I want C to always hold a snapshot of B when it (C) is created and saved and not directly reference the instance of B that is referenced by A.

B should be modifiable and A should point to the latest version of B.

I could do this manually by implementing equals method, checking for equality and nullifying the id field of B when necessary before calling saveOrUpdate(). Is there a built in way in Hibernate or simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give Hibernate Interceptors a quick read.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html

Answer (score 0):

try giving Hibernate [DefaultSaveOrUpdateListener](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=977720) a read, this listener (when configured) will be called to do all the heavy lifting of saving the object, its this listener which determines of an object needs to be saved or updated.

your logic to decide to save/update/create a new object for a dirty object can be done here.

Comment: how can I determine if the entity is dirty from the event object?

Comment: there is a method called isDirty(), try that.